# SQL: how to reference user inputs multiple times for a WHERE list?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I'm not sure the right buzzwords to use, but how to use a single input at the top of the query that can then be used many times throughout the query? I'd like to reduce and limit the risk of error and missing a filter entry for the next user.

```
where column1 in ('a','b',...'n')
```

assign this to a variable or something at the top of the SQL file, to limit risk of error.

Comment: *Assign this to a variable*: what exactly do you want to assign? Please show us more code so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've got a long code I wrote that uses multiple CTE's, conditional aggregation and joins.  Currently, I have the same several WHERE filters listed a few times throughout the code. Is there a way to identify this at the top of the sql text then reference later?

Comment: Since you're already using a CTE, maybe you can just make the values in your IN clause its own CTE table expression, and then instead of repeating the values just reference the CTE table's alias.

Comment: how would I do this?

Comment: @surfer349 I'll put an example together in the answers section.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I've done this before, using the SPLIT_TO_TABLE function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_names (fname varchar(20));
INSERT INTO tmp_names 
VALUES ('rich'), ('joe'), ('sally'), ('bill'), ('ted');

SELECT * 
FROM   tmp_names
WHERE fname in (
  SELECT t.value 
  FROM   TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE('sally,ted', ',')) as t);--2 records returned

set my_in_stmt = 'sally,ted';
SELECT * 
FROM   tmp_names
WHERE fname in (
  SELECT t.value 
  FROM   TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE($my_in_stmt, ',')) as t); --2 records returned
```

Documentation of the SPLIT_TO_TABLE function is at:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html

Answer (score 0):

You can place the list into a CTE table using a values clause, and then do an IN on the selection from that table.

```
create temporary table foo (column1 string);

insert into foo (column1) values ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('a'), ('b'), ('c');

select * from foo where column1 in ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');

with 
VALUE_LIST(vals) as
(
    select * from values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f'),('g')
)
select * from foo where column1 in (select vals from value_list)
```

You can reference the VALUE_LIST table in the CTE as many times as you need and keep it updated in one location.